# Quotient of ring of polynomials over ℤ

Tags: abstract-algebra

The quotient ℤ[X]/(X-3) is isomorphic to ℤ. But here f(x) = x-3 is reducible in ℤ[X] because it has root 3 in Z. So how come the quotient is isomorphic to ℤ  (in which case it will be an integral domain).

Comment: $x-3$ is irreducible.

Comment: Is there a theorem that says "if a polynomial $p\in\Bbb Z [X]$ has a root, then it is reducible"? Because it looks more like something that can be *erroneously extrapolated* from the way an *actual* theorem is frequenly used, rather than a theorem itself.

Comment: If the polynomial over ℤ has root in ℤ, is it not reducible??

Comment: Not if it has degree $1$. The theorem you're alluding to asserts that if $f$ has a root such as $3$, then it is divisible  by $X-3$, and conversely. This means it is reducible  only if $f\ne X-3$.